# Getting last 7 days data from days name like sunday, monday, tuesday etc in linq asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I want to fetch data by last week days like last Sunday, last Monday and so on 7 days. I wrote this query but I returns null.

```
var dateCriteria = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
var one = _context.Sale.Where(m => m.Date >= dateCriteria && m.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == 
"Sunday");
```

Answer (score 1):

DayOfWeek is enum. So just use it without conversion:

```
var dateCriteria = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
var one = _context.Sale.Where(m => m.Date >= dateCriteria && m.Date.DayOfWeek == 
DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: There cannot be Where cluase becuase there will be only one Sunday in a week. If I use FirstOrDefault then it give me error InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but here is what I would do to get the last Sunday's sales.

```
 var one = _context.Sale.Where(m => m.Date == GetLast(DayOfWeek.Sunday));

 private DateTime GetLast(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {
     var currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
     var currentDayOfWeek = (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek;

     if (currentDayOfWeek <= (int)dayOfWeek) {
         currentDayOfWeek = currentDayOfWeek + 7;
     }
     int daysToExtract = currentDayOfWeek - (int)dayOfWeek;

     return currentDate.AddDays(-daysToExtract);
 }
```